# Access Run-Time Error 3075

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm having trouble getting the following report to run. I keep getting the run-time error 3075.The reportText is the text box field on the form. The error seems to be in the reportsearch field.

Private Sub Command284_Click()

Dim reportsearch As String
Dim reportText As String

If IsNull(Me.txtReport.Value) Then
     MsgBox "This box must contin a keyword"
     Me.txtReport.SetFocus

Else
reportText = Me.txtReport.Value

reportsearch = "SELECT * FROM NCECBVI WHERE ([Last Name] LIKE ""*" & reportText & "*"" OR ([First Name] LIKE ""*" & reportText & "*""))"

DoCmd.OpenReport "NCECBVI-Report", acPreview, , reportsearch

End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The `WhereCondition` parameter of the `OpenReport` command should just contain the condition itself with no other syntax around it. Change your `reportsearch` assignment to:

```
reportsearch = "[Last Name] LIKE """ & reportText & """ OR [First Name] LIKE """ & reportText & """"
```

Also, you are using `LIKE` in the condition, but you don't have any wildcard characters. Either change `LIKE` to `=` or use wildcards to get matches that contain the entered string:

```
reportsearch = "[Last Name] LIKE ""*" & reportText & "*"" OR [First Name] LIKE ""*" & reportText & "*"""
```